# Conditional formatting on cells we apply a formula on

Tags: google-sheets, max, google-sheets-formula, min, conditional-formatting

Let's say you have a table containing cells that have values generated from a formula.
The value in those cells all start with a number (until the separation with a ";" ).
Now you'd like to apply a range of colors to the cells on this table, based on how high this number is.

Is it possible to have such a formula in conditional formatting ?

Sheet used for test :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MUkYDPoR1NxB8qWcYr_2Fp91FgUbnUOpfGd7EUuWCOg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at this time color scale of conditional formatting can not be set to your B2:D5 range due to its limitation. if there are not many values in your dataset you can use regular conditional formatting where you can use MAX and MIN and then LARGE  and SMALL to return 2nd, 3rd, etc. a lot of setting it up but it would work.

example:

```
=MAX(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(B$2:B$5; "(.*);")*1))=REGEXEXTRACT(B2; "(.*);")*1
```

---

```
=MIN(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(B$2:B$5; "(.*);")*1))=REGEXEXTRACT(B2; "(.*);")*1
```

---

```
=LARGE(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(B$2:B$5; "(.*);")*1); 2)=REGEXEXTRACT(B2; "(.*);")*1
```

---

```
=SMALL(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(B$2:B$5; "(.*);")*1); 2)=REGEXEXTRACT(B2; "(.*);")*1
```

[image]

Comment: Too bad that we cannot do it at this time. How would do it with regular condition formatting as you say here ?

Comment: @Seb answer updated